# Electron make Http request behind corporate proxy

Tags: angularjs, electron

I have a stand alone application made with Electron and AngularJs.

I would like to make some HttpRequest like

```
return {
    PostData: function (path, method, json) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(path + method, json)
            .then(function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }, function (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }}
```

but i'm having troubles to reach some endpoint due to a 407 code (Proxy authentication)

I would like to know if there is a way through Electron to bypass it and
write something like:

```
http://username:password@proxyIp:ProxyPort
```

thank u a lot in advance